# Converting LINQ to dictionary in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to convert LINQ to dictionary in vb.net, but can't seem to understand why I get all these exceptions thrown at me.

All I'm trying to do, is to sort by descending value with help from LINQ.

Here's my code:

```
'Declaring my primary dictionary    
Dim nameValDict As New Dictionary(Of Object, Object)
```

... nameValDict is now getting filled up with data

```
'Declaring temporary sorted dictionary with LINQ
Dim sortedDict = (From entry In nameValDict Order By entry.Value Descending Select entry)

'Replace with sorted results from LINQ
nameValDict = sortedDict.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(x) x.Value)
```

Exception: System.ArgumentException (Object should be of type Double) - On last line.

I'll appreciate ANY help.

Comment: Check [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) from msdn.

Comment: SortedDictionary only sort on keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its properly your `Order By` in this statement:
 `From entry In nameValDict Order By entry.Value Descending Select entry`

Becuase `entry.Value` is of type `Object`, and you can't sort desending on Object. The program doesnt know how to *compare* `Object`s against eachother.

Comment: Thank you!

I've changed the first line to: Dim nameValDict As New Dictionary(Of Object, Integer) - That way the value is an integer, and is now comparable.